# Toggle checkbox in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make this code hide the attribute bridge if it is unchecked and revert it back if it is checked again?

```
var bridge = new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'Bridge',
            opacity: opacity,
            //visible: false,
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: geoserverUrlPath + '/geoserver/wms',
                params:{
                    'LAYERS':'pasco_benim:bridge',
                    'TILED': true
                },
                serverType: 'geoserver'
            }),
            layerName: 'bridge'
        });     

            bridge.on('change:visible', function(){
                    //alert("alert");
                    $('#bridge').hide();
            });
```

Comment: can you add html too so that we can check  OR try once `bridge.on('change', function(){$('#bridge').toggle(); });`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If `bridge` is a `type=checkbox` input than you could try like

```
 $('#bridge').toggle();
```

or if you want to be more specific use `this.checked` or `!this.checked` to invert logic:

```
bridge.on('change', function() {
    $('#bridge').toggle( this.checked );
});
```

Since you didn't provided any Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, here's mine:

```js
const bridge = $("#bridge-input"),
      bridgeDiv = $("#bridge");


bridge.on('change', ()=> bridgeDiv.toggle( this.checked ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type=checkbox id=bridge-input>
<div id=bridge>BUNGALUNGA</div>
```

Comment: Thank mate! but it doesn't work. 
This is working when I uncheck it:
 `           bridge.on('change:visible', function(){ `
                    $('#bridge').hide();
            });
`
maybe I can add if statement to this?